# Unable to connect to WSDL

Tags: php, web-services, soap, https

I was working with older version of OpenSSL(OpenSSL 0.9.8o) and I was forced to use newer OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips as the result I was unable to connect to WSDL:

`Message: SoapClient::SoapClient(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed`

I need to disable SSL certification check, I tried:

```php
    $client = new SoapClient("https://IP:443/sdk/vimService?wsdl",
        array(
            "trace" => 1,
            "location" => "https://IP:443/sdk/",
            "stream_context" => stream_context_create(
                array(
                    'ssl' => array(
                        'verify_peer'       => false,
                        'allow_self_signed' => true,
                    )
                )
            )
        ) 
    );
```

`

And it throw:

`Message: SoapClient::SoapClient(): Peer certificate CN=`localhost.localdom' did not match expected CN=`SAME IP AS IN SoapClient()'`

Then I added `'peer_name'=> 'localhost.localdom',` in `stream_context` and then it says XML file is empty:

`Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document`

PHP 5.5

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Okey, I was able to found issue.

**You can avoid this mess using stable PHP 5.5 version**

Recently I learned that error: "looks like we got no XML document" is caused because of PHP version - PHP 5.6 in 5.5 working like a charm.

### How to fix it in PHP 5.6

1) Remove SSL certificate check in PHP 5.6:

In 5.6 version SSL certification was enabled by default, so if you want to disabled it you must pass context stream:

```php
    "stream_context" => stream_context_create(
        array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer'       => false,
                'verify_peer_name'  => false,
            )
        )
    )
```

2) Deleted `?wsdl` and added `.wsdl` instead (with `?wsdl`, it didn't worke for me)

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient("https://IP:443/sdk/vimService.wsdl",
    array(
        "trace" => 1,
        "location" => "https://IP:443/sdk/",
        'exceptions' => 1,
        "stream_context" => stream_context_create(
            array(
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer'       => false,
                    'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                )
            )
        )
    ) 
);


$soapmsg["_this"] = array( "_" => "ServiceInstance", "type" => "ServiceInstance");

$result = $client->RetrieveServiceContent($soapmsg);
$ServiceContent = $result->returnval;

$soapmsg = NULL;
$soapmsg["_this"] = $ServiceContent->sessionManager;
$soapmsg["userName"] = "USERNAME";
$soapmsg["password"] = "PASSWORD";

$result = $client->Login($soapmsg);
$UserSession = $result->returnval;

echo "User, " . $UserSession->userName . ", successfully logged in!\n";

$soapmsg = NULL;
$soapmsg["_this"] = $ServiceContent->sessionManager;
$result = $client->Logout($soapmsg);
```

Comment: I had the same issue using the Salesforce PHP Toolkit (https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Toolkit_for_PHP) when upgrading to PHP 5.6, but this has solved it. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same bug with ubuntu 14.10 and php5.6.9
1) - helped me, the best answer!

Comment: Adding ssl params solves my problem                                                                               "stream_context" => stream_context_create(
                array(
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer'       => false,
                    'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                )
            )
        )

Answer (score 2):

In my case stream_context_create didn't worked.
So I download this file here : https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

and placed it in my localhost as : F:\xampp\apache\cert.pem
and gave the same path for 
openssl.cafile=F:\xampp\apache\cert.pem in my phpini

This made the localhost to acquire certificate and things worked great...!!
Posting this in case this may help some one going through my situation.

Comment: Indeed, this is really good solution for localhost testing app.

Answer (score 2):

In my case was needed to add the crypt_method

```
"stream_context" => stream_context_create(
        array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer'       => true,
                'verify_peer_name'  => true,
                'crypto_method' => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT
            )
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case "stream_context" did the magic, i've just added the code :

```
`"stream_context" => stream_context_create(
   array(
      'ssl' => array(
           'verify_peer'       => false,
           'verify_peer_name'  => false,
      )
   )
)`
```