# How do I fix error on SOAP call in my OpenCart PHP code?

Tags: php, soap, opencart

I'm trying to make a SOAP call in my PHP code. The code is in file1.php, while the SOAP is in the WSDL file, soap.xml. The new  SoapClient() is in line 150

file1.php is a controller file inside OpenCart 2.3

```
$user = 'user';
$password = 'password';
$wsdl = 'soap.xml'

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl,array('login' => "$user", 'password' => "$password", 'encoding'=>'ISO-8859-1', 'trace'=>1, 'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array('https' => array('protocol_version' => 1.0) ) ), 'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
```

Here is the error I keep getting:

```
SoapClient::SoapClient(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL

Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in <b>file1.php</b> on line <b>150</b><b>Warning</b>: SoapClient::SoapClient(): Failed to enable crypto in <b>file1</b> on line <b>150</b><b>Warning</b>: SoapClient::SoapClient (https://soap.xml): failed to open stream: operation failed in <b>file1.php</b> on line <b>150</b><b>Warning</b>: SoapClient::SoapClient(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;https:soap.xml&quot; in <b>file1.php</b> on line <b>150</b>
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Which version of PHP do you use ?

Comment: We're using PHP 5.6.26 on SOAP 1.1

Comment: Maybe this can help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142227/unable-to-connect-to-wsdl

Comment: Thanks, I'll go check it out

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked the link suggested by Jean-maxime Bouloc. I've tweaked the new SoapClient() call as follows:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl,array('login' => "$user", 'password' => "$password", 'encoding'=>'ISO-8859-1', 'trace'=>1, 'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array('https' => array('protocol_version' => 1.0), 'ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name'=> false,) ) ), 'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
```

I'd like to give credit to Jean-maxime Bouloc for helping me out.